# Time Counter (using flipclock)

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

Okay, I love this Flip Clock!! Awesome!

The problem I'm having is that the timer is not lined up right. I took a screen shot, here it is:
http://s22.postimg.org/9v19oa0oh/flip_Counter_Not_Working.jpg

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

This is on a wordpress site, but I added the code to the head instead of just in the main content html... like this:

```
  <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/compiled/flipclock.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/js/compiled/flipclock.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
  </head>
```

Obviously there was a lot more stuff in the head, I just copied those between the head tags...
and then in the HTML I put the other code:

```
  <div class="clock"></div>
  <script>var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock("[php] echo time() - $_StartingTime;[/php]");</script>
```

The clock appears as you can see in the screenshot, but it is not lined up.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

btw, here is the HTML that the php page outputs:

```
  <div class="clock"></div>
  <p><script language="JavaScript">
  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock("6447");</script></p>
```

So the php does put the time right, but even if I remove the "" around the starting time, because their sample does not have any quote marks at all, it still does this. I added the "" marks to see if it fixed it, but it did not.

I hope someone knows what I did wrong. I've been working on this for like 9 hours now. I'm about to give up and just make it use text instead of this nice interface.

Thanks in advance if you can help me. :)
-Richard

Comment: Try loading first the stylesheet and later the js files

Comment: Make sure you're not using css rules that would affect `div.clock`.

Comment: Ok, I moved the stylesheet to the top of the head, just under where it starts, the js files are now below it. So that reversed the order, still same issue.

Comment: I changed clock to clock2 and that did not fix it either, same issue. not lined up right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the SomoSocial theme's CSS... when I remove that code from a test page I created out of the source code of my page, then the page looked terrible because the theme look and feel went away, but then the Flipclock looked normal.

So I guess I have to find the conflict and rename them or something.

Comment: Instead of fixing it, I pulled it in with a iframe, someone somewhere else suggested that, and it worked. don't know why I did not think of that. :) lol.... anyhow, it is working with the iframe. Glad that saved me time over figuring out the conflict and just redoing it. that may have taken forever. anyhow, it is working. - DONE :)